# Forward-declaring class from generic namespace (in std::hash

Tags: c++, c++11, hash, namespaces, forward-declaration

I'm struggling with a forward declaration. B references A, and A uses a std::vector of B. **Both A and B are defined in the generic (no) namespace.**

Forward declaring B in the header of A does the job for the members in A. Nevertheless, I defined the hash function for A in the same header file, and it causes trouble.

```
#include "B.h"
class B;
class A{
public:
   std::vector<B> bs; 
}

namespace std
{
template <>
struct hash<A>
{
    size_t operator()(const A& k) const
    {
        std::size_t seed = 0;
        boost::hash_combine(seed, k.foo);
        boost::hash_combine(seed, k.bar);
        for(B &b:k.bs){
            boost::hash_combine(seed, b.abc);
        }

        return seed;
    }
};
}
```

The function accesses the vector of B's and thus also requires the forward declaration. Nevertheless, it doesn't make use of the forward declaration in the parent header file. Unfortunately, I can't forward-declare it again within namespace std, because this will create ambiguity between the definitions. Any idea?

Comment: Have you tried using `friend`?

Comment: I don't see `foo` and `bar` as members of `A`. Please post your errors.

Comment: Incomplete type is the first error; adding another forward declaration to B in the std namespace leads to an ambiguity problem.

Comment: By the way - my current workaround is to add a member function to A which gives me the abc values from b, which are integers. This way, there is no need to handle type B in the hash function, but it's clearly a design flaw with a negative effect on performance.

Answer (score 1):

You could move the definition of `hash<A>::operator()` into your source file. So:

```
// A.h
#include <vector>
#include <functional>

struct B;

struct A {
    std::vector<B> bs;
};

namespace std {
    template <>
    struct hash<A> {
        size_t operator()(const A& ) const;
    };
}
```

```
// A.cpp
#include "B.h"

// now, B is complete, so we can define operator()
size_t std::hash<A>::operator()(const A& k) const
{
    std::size_t seed = 0;
    boost::hash_combine(seed, k.foo);
    boost::hash_combine(seed, k.bar);
    for(const B& b : k.bs){
        boost::hash_combine(seed, b.abc);
    }

    return seed;
}
```

Comment: Declaring a `std::vector<?>` where `?` is an incomplete type is technically an ill-formed program, no diagnostic required.  This is a flaw in the standard.  Or has it been fixed?

Comment: @Yakk We have this now: "An incomplete type `T` may be used when instantiating `vector` if the allocator satisfies the allocator completeness
requirements 17.6.3.5.1. `T` shall be complete before any member of the resulting specialization of vector is referenced."

Comment: @Yakk [vector.overview]/3